# Mockito mock objects returns null

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I try to implement some tests for my JSF application and for the mocks I am using mockito. (I also use spring)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GeneralConfigServiceImplTest  {

    private GeneralConfigService generalConfigService;

    @Mock
    private GeneralConfigDAO generalConfigDAO;

    @Mock
    private GeneralConfig gen;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        generalConfigService = new GeneralConfigService();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(generalConfigService, "generalConfigDAO", generalConfigDAO);                  
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddGeneralConfigCallDAOSuccess() throws DAOException, EntityNullException, IllegalEntityArgumentException, ParseException, EntityPersistException {
        gen = createGeneralConfigs("label", "value");

        generalConfigService.setInstance(gen);
        generalConfigService.persist();
        log.info(generalConfigService.getInstance().toString());
    }
}
```

The test succeeds, but when I want to retrieve the instance with the `getInstance` method. All Parameters which I have set before (via the constructor before) are null. 
I am new to mocked objects, so is this behavior normal, or is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to mocking as you don't mock the object in question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It really depends on GeneralConfigService#getInstance() implementation. Also you can simplify your test code a lot if you use `@InjectMocks` annotation.

When using `MockitoJUnitRunner` you don't need to initialize mocks and inject your dependencies manually:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GeneralConfigServiceImplTest  {

    @InjectMocks
    private GeneralConfigService generalConfigService;

    @Mock
    private GeneralConfigDAO generalConfigDAO;

    @Test
    public void testAddGeneralConfigCallDAOSuccess() {
       // generalConfigService is already instantiated and populated with dependencies here
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just leaving this here: https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Comment: I get this error - java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability

Answer (score 14):

My problem here was the incorrect import for `Test` anotation:

Was

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

Correct

`import org.junit.Test;`

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Andrew 4.x I guess. Not access to the code right now.

Answer (score 13):

Don't forget to use

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

If you are Mocking object through annotation i.e. `@Mock Objectname`

Comment: initMocks is not required when using the Mockito JUnit runner.

Comment: today I am using mock in a main class. yea~

Comment: in junit it does not need this statement indeed. but on that day, i was running it in a main method which was not a junit method, and your answer helped. :)

Comment: Cool, Sounds great :)

Comment: MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) IS DEPRECATED

Answer (score 8):

All method calls to `Mockito` mocks return null by default. If you want it to return something else you need to tell it to do so via a `when` statement.

It seems the you are thinking that the following will work... you call `setInstance` and then expect `getInstance` to return the value that was passed to `setInstance` since this is how the DAO would work. If this is what you are attempting, you shouldn't test `setInstance` by then calling `getInstance` since `getInstance` will return whatever you have configured the mock to return and will have no relation to what was passed to `setInstance`. Instead, use `verify` to validate that the appropriate method of the `DAO` was called from the `setInstance` method.

For example, if `GeneralConfigService.setInstance` calls `GeneralConfigDAO.setInstance` then your test should look like this...

```
@Test
public void testAddGeneralConfigCallDAOSuccess() throws DAOException, EntityNullException, IllegalEntityArgumentException, ParseException, EntityPersistException {
    gen = createGeneralConfigs("label", "value");

    generalConfigService.setInstance(gen);
    generalConfigService.persist();

    verify(genConfigDAO).setInstance(sameInstance(gen));
}
```

Also, if `gen` is a mock (via `@Mock`) why are you assigning it to something else via `gen = createGeneralConfigs...`

Answer (score 3):

This thread is an old one, but I got the same problem with junit5 (v5.8.2) and mockito (mockito-core:jar:4.5.1) and none of the answers here helped me. After a 1.5 hours search I found this article:

https://mincong.io/2020/04/19/mockito-junit5/

which helped me! I used the first solution, so I added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.28.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

as new dependency and I annotated my class with the following annotation (and **I removed** the *@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)* annotation):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

Please find the explanation in the article. I hope this help to others as well!