# WebTestclient is throwing Null Exception tough @Autowire is there

Tags: java, webclient

The project is spring boot application.
When trying to access the api from in test case as webtestclient it is throwing nullpoint exception.

The class and the Restcontroller an and the testclass as follows

This is the class

```
@Component
public class GetMessage {
@Async
public void fetchData( fileType Type, String requestBody) {

        switch (A) {
            case a:
                operation(requestBody);
             break;
            case b:
                 // do some Operation
            break;
            default:
             break;
         }
 }
}
```

Rest controller

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("api/school/student-receiver/assignment")
public class  FileReceiverRestController {

@Autowired
    private objectMapper mapper;

@PostMapping(path = "/file", consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> receivefile(@RequestBody String reqBody) {        

    mapper.fetchData(fileType.A ,String reqBody);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(CALL_RESP, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Test class

```
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class E2ETest {

  @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient ;

   String ReceiverUrl="api/school/student-receiver/assignment/file"

     @Test
     pubilic void Testapi()
    {
    webTestClient  //====> facing null exception
            .post().uri(ReceiverUrl)
            //.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(requestPayload)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            // then
            .expectStatus().isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
   }
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
at  E2ETest.Testapi(E2ETest.java:176)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

Comment: It would be better if you provide additional log of the NPE.

Comment: Did you miss @SpringBootTest?

Comment: Could anyone please help.

Comment: This isn't a spring based test so `@Autowired` is being ignored. At `@SpringBootTest` or use a proper slice like `@WebMvcTest`. Else it won't work .

Comment: Check if you are able to solve with the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714624/11761331

Answer (score 1):

From how I understand this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12318) from the Spring Boot project, using `@AutoconfigureWebTestClient` only works if you are testing a WebFlux application. As you are using Spring MVC (Tomcat) and *just* want to make use of the `WebClient` /`WebTestClient`, this might be the reason.

The Javadoc of `@AutoconfigureWebTestClient` also adds a hint on this:

```
/**
 * Annotation that can be applied to a test class to enable a {@link WebTestClient}. At
 * the moment, only WebFlux applications are supported.
 *
 * @author Stephane Nicoll
 * @since 2.0.0
 * @see WebTestClientAutoConfiguration
 */
```

Nevertheless, what works is to use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` for a test. This will ensure to autoconfigure `TestRestTemplate` and `WebTestClient` in the background:

```
// if you are using JUnit 4 this is also needed
// @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class WebTestClientAccessTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webTestClient;

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

  @Test
  public void notNull() {
    assertNotNull(webTestClient);
    assertNotNull(testRestTemplate);
  }
}
```

This will start the whole Spring context and you can access your application from *outside* using the client.

If you don't want to start the embedded Tomcat and load all beans, you can take a look at `@WebMvcTest` to focus on testing your web-layer. For this, you'll use `MockMvc` and work with a mocked servlet environment. This [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) from Spring Boot provides a good introduction.

Further information can be found at the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features).